# How to set background color limited on height

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, elementor

I have used this piece of code to have a background split in 2 parts with 2 different colors

```
body {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
         90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff5353",endColorstr="#fd9b78",GradientType=1);
}
```

but I want to have this background limited on height , I dont want it to expand all the way to the bottom of my product page, with this code my product page look like this :

[image: before]

But I would like to achieve that result

[image: after]

How can I do that please

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of examples around the internet for this case. You simply use `background-size`, here is the documentaion: [CSS Backgrounds](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-size) . In your case this will look like:

```
body {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(
         90deg, rgba(255,83,83,1) 0%, rgba(255,83,83,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 50%, rgba(253,155,120,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff5353",endColorstr="#fd9b78",GradientType=1);
    -o-background-size: auto 400px;
    -webkit-background-size:auto 400px;
    -moz-background-size: auto 400px;
    background-size: auto 400px;
}
```

The first parameter of `background-size` is width, the second is height. So this example will make your background a size of `400px`.

Comment: I found  the class responsible of the background in the specific location , it is .elementor-1313 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6eb2ffa:not(.elementor-motion-effects-element-type-background), .elementor-1313 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6eb2ffa > .elementor-motion-effects-container > .elementor-motion-effects-layer {
    background-color: #FFE66A;
   BUT WHEN I ADD FOR EXAMPLE   background-size: auto 10px;  nothing happens

Comment: @jukilofabra Terms like `elementor-element-6eb2ffa` looks dynamically to me. Try to attach your own class to the element.